# `-p` is for what in creating virtual environment command of Django

Tags: django

Django creates virtual environment alternatively applies command:

```
virtualenv -p python3 .
```

I have typed over 30 times of the commands.
The meaning of `-p` is a ghost for me.To search it several times,I failed to get its explanation.
I wonder it might be out of the scope of my concepts and vocabulary.

Comment: It's a name of python binary you want to use. Or a path to it (`-p /usr/bin/python3.6` for example). See `virtualenv --help` for more details.

Comment: great, p for path

Comment: `p` for `python` :) you can even use `--python python3` instead of just `-p python3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-p sets which python interpreter to use

See the vitrualenv reference here https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/